# How do I get the checked state of all the tree items from QTreeView?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tree, pyqt, treeview

How do I get the checked state of all the tree items, and store them back into self._data ?

I use this data structure to populate the tree

```
{
  "camera": {
    "ver": 8,
    "new_ver": 10
  },
  "char": {
    "bob": {
      "ver": 2,
      "new_ver": 20
    },
    "aston": {
      "ver": 4,
      "new_ver": 13
    }
  }
}
```

And the code is

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import uic
import os

# enable ctrl-c to kill the app
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

import json
from pprint import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict

data_dict = OrderedDict([('camera', OrderedDict([('ver', '8'), ('new_ver', '10')])),
                         ('char',
                          OrderedDict([
                              ('bob', OrderedDict(
                                  [('ver', '2'), ('new_ver', '20')])),
                              ('aston', OrderedDict(
                                  [('ver', '4'), ('new_ver', '13')]))
                          ]))
                         ])


pprint(data_dict)


class AssetModel(QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AssetModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data_dict

    # def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):

    #     if index.isValid():
    #         if role == Qt.DisplayRole:

    # def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
    #     print 'in setData'
    #     if index.isValid():
    #         print 'index:',index.row(),'value:',value.toPyObject(),role
    #         if index.row()==0 and role==Qt.CheckStateRole:
    #             # self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
    #             print 'need to update self._data'
    #         return True
    #     return False


class MyWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.model = AssetModel()

        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)

        self.button = QPushButton('Print')

        layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.initialLoad()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.get_data)

    def initialLoad(self):
        # self.model.load()
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.populateTree()

    def populateTree(self):
        for k in data_dict.keys():
            parent1 = QStandardItem(k)
            parent1.setCheckable(True)

            if k == 'char':
                for j in data_dict[k].keys():
                    char_name = QStandardItem(j)
                    char_name.setCheckable(True)

                    ver_data = data_dict[k][j].values()
                    children = [QStandardItem(x)
                                for x in ver_data]

                    if int(ver_data[0]) < int(ver_data[1]):
                        char_name.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
                        parent1.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

                    parent1.appendRow([char_name] + children)

                self.model.appendRow(parent1)
            else:
                ver_data = data_dict[k].values()
                children = [QStandardItem(x) for x in ver_data]
                self.model.appendRow([parent1]+children)

                if int(ver_data[0]) < int(ver_data[1]):
                    parent1.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

        self.headers = ['asset', 'ver', 'new_ver']
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.headers)
        self.treeView.expandAll()

        for i in range(len(self.headers)):
            self.treeView.resizeColumnToContents(i)

    def get_data(self):
        # print the data shown on tree
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The expected result is when you click the push button, it prints out this structure: assuming camera and bob are checked, aston is unchecked

```
{
  "camera": {
    "ver": 8,
    "new_ver": 10,
    "checked":1
  },
  "char": {
    "bob": {
      "ver": 2,
      "new_ver": 20,
      "checked":1
    },
    "aston": {
      "ver": 4,
      "new_ver": 13,
      "checked":0
    }
  }
}
```

should I just iterate the treeview to get the result ?

[image: img]

Comment: Saving the structure has the same logic as populating from it. The values just go from tree to dict, rather than dict to tree.

Answer (score 0):

Only by iterating, implement it in a recursive way.
Work on the modal directly, not on the view.